# how to query all staking rewards on polkadot.js given an access to archive node

Tags: blockchain, substrate, polkadot, polkadot-js

so I'm looking at this api docs on polkadot.js https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage#staking
but I could not figure which one to use to actually query all the staking rewards given an account ID / publish address.

I was thinking I would have to loop for each era. but which one returns the staking rewards. so than I can calculate a total overtime? thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

In general, the node isn't used for querying *historical* state. Instead you very likely want to use an indexer service that generates data that is much easier to get queries on. There are a few options, but one of the most supported is [substrate archive](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-archive) that I would suggest you use.

Alternatively you can look to [substrate compatible block explorers](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/en/build-tools-index#block-explorers) to see what they do for this in their source code.